# jQuery UI Dialog default options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-8

I'm using jQuery UI Dialog from Drupal 8 core (jQuery UI Dialog 1.11.4)  to show node in modal, but default options doesn't suits me and I need to change them.

To show node (node id 12 in this example) in modal I'm using this from Drupal:

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/12">SHOW NODE</a>
```

I tried to change defaults like this:

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
            modal: true,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            fluid: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeText: Drupal.t('Close it'),
            hide: 'fadeOut',
            show: 'fadeIn'
          });
```

but I'm got empty modal with options I defined.

How I can just change these options and make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add options to Dialog using "data-dialog-options" attribute.
For example:

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options='{"width":"100%", "height":"100%", "fluid":"true", "resizable":"false", "hide":"fadeOut", "show":"fadeIn"}' href="/node/12">SHOW NODE</a>
```